# Rails error: ExecJS::ProgramError in Posts#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Just installed a fresh rails installation. Followed the steps in [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pPy0GQJLZUM). At 14:04, the index page should appear.

Got this error when running my index page:

```
ExecJS::ProgramError in Posts#index
Showing C:/Sites/Simpleblog/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #7 raised:
TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method
Extracted source (around line #7):

    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>


Rails.root: C:/Sites/Simpleblog
```

Line 7 is:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

Here is routes.rb:

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

root 'posts#index'  



end
```

Here is posts_controller:

```rb
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    def index

    end
end
```

Comment: install `execjs` gem and try .